# Pycharm does not import package, while iPython does

Tags: python, pycharm, windows-10

I am trying to run the following python script in Pycharm:

```
import tensorflow as tf

hello = tf.constant("hello TensorFlow!")
sess=tf.Session()
print(sess.run(hello))
```

but I get an error with the final statement being:

> AttributeError: type object 'h5py.h5r.Reference' has no attribute **'__reduce_cython__'**

However the same script executes ok with iPython, thus I suspect the problem is in Pycharm.

I set the correct interpreter in Pycharm which points to the conda env, moreover I found [similar problem](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-29580) and set manually `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` to `C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v9.0\lib\x64`.

This did not do the job either.

Does anybody know what else am I supposed to do?

I am using:

- Python 3.6
- Pycharm 2018.3.5 (community edition)
- Windows 10

Comment: Not too sure but is the cuda toolkit in your path. Does Cython and tensorflow show up in the Pycharm Project Interpreter list?

Comment: @GRAYgoose124 they are both listed.

Comment: Does it work with python, (not iPython)? If not, the problem is not within PyCharm. If yes, open the PyCharm-console and the python-console and run `import sys;sys.executable`. If both return different things, PyCharm uses a different executable and you can configure that in the settings ("Project Iterpreter").

Comment: python-console: `>>> import sys;sys.executable
>>>'C:\\Users\\<user>\\Anaconda3\\envs\\mag\\python.exe'` 
Pycharm console: `import sys;print(sys.executable)` returns `C:\Users\<user>\Anaconda3\envs\mag\python.exe`

Answer (score 1):

Downgrading the h5py from `2.9.0` which came preinstalled with tensorflow to `2.8.0` solves the problem.

I don't know if it is the best solution, but for now it solves the problem.